# iPhone . indexed attributes

Tags: iphone, database, database-design, core-data

What are the advantages or disadvantages of turning ON the index property of an attribute on a core data entity?

I have a database with about 300 items. Each item has a description in 4 languages. The description is about 40 characters long, generally less. I have 4 additional attributes on other entities that also are descriptions in four languages, also with less than 40 chars.

Will it be necessary to turn the index for all these 8 attributes? is there any advantage or disadvantage?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Advantages of an index: faster search on that field.

Disadvantages: inserts are slower and additional storage space is required.

In a table of only 300 rows, it probably won't make much of a difference either way. But you will have to profile your particular app to be sure.

Comment: Thanks. I have tested either way and did not find any perceptive difference. I suppose I have a small number of rows but as this will not be larger than that, I think I will keep that off.